# using stimulsoft in .net core

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, stimulsoft

I have used `stimulsoft` in my .net project with no problem so far, but when I tried to migrate the project to .net core, things didn't work. Here is the procedure in which I use the stimulsoft library:

```
report = new StiReport();
report.Load("test.mrt");
report.Compile(); //--> here I get System.Windows.Forms load exception
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Html, memoryStream); //--> here I get User32.dll load exception
```

So first of all, I got the following error in compile phase:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then I commented compile line but I got the following error in Export phase:

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'User32.dll': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
```

I have installed `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore` version `2018.2.3` from nuget. Although this package is targeting .net core, it is still depends on platform dependent modules. Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone help please?

PS: I am running the application on `ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 1):

`Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore` does not support `StiReport.Compile()` on .NET Core yet (as of version 2018.2.3).

This method is necessary for a C# code in a report to work (`<Script>` element). So if your report depends on the C# code inside, you should switch back to the .NET Framework and `Stimulsoft.Reports.Net`.

Or just remove the line with `Compile()` invocation otherwise, thus the export would work smoothly on Windows (but without any dynamic modifications done by the C# code in the report).

Unfortunately, I haven't had experience running Stimulsoft reports under Linux, so can't tell you about the dependency on `User32.dll`. But you can ask the support, they're quite responsive.